# Way to open Google Map V3 InfoBox from click in sidebar

Tags: google-maps

I am using Info box plugin in google map v3

I want to replicate the same functioning as seen here

http://coolhunting.com/local/#/metroarea/chicago/jack-spade/

Basically I want that whenever some one click on sidebar , respective info box should open in map.

I have added a onclick function on click on element in sidebar , but not sure what should I do in that function

Here is the code I have

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
      <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
          body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map_canvas { height: 50% }
        </style>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api    /js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="js/infobox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(66.672962361614566, 12.56587028503418);

    var myMapOptions = {
         zoom:5
        ,center: latlng
        ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        ,streetViewControl: false
    };
    var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);
// namn
var name=[];
name.push('Test 1');
name.push('Test 2');

// positioner
var position=[];
position.push(new google.maps.LatLng(66.667093265894245,12.581255435943604));
position.push(new google.maps.LatLng(62.66453963191134, 12.584795951843262));

// infoboxes
var infobox = [];
infobox.push("<div>Hello 1</div>");
infobox.push("<div>Hello 2</div>");

var markers=new Array();


for (i = 0; i < position.length; i += 1) {
// Call function
createMarkers(position[i], infobox[i], name[i]);


}

function createMarkers(position,content,name) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: theMap,
        draggable: false,
        position: position,
        visible: true,
        title: name
    });
markers.push(marker);
    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "background: #ffffff; width: 300px; height: 70px; padding: 5px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = content;

    var myOptions = {
         content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-37, -120)
        ,zIndex: null
        ,boxStyle: { 
            background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
            ,opacity: 1
            ,width: "300px"
         }
        ,closeBoxMargin: "5px 5px 5px 5px"
        ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
    };

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        ib.open(theMap, this);
    });

    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
 //ib.open(theMap, marker);

    }

}
function show_marker(){

}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div><div><a onclick="show_marker()" href="javascript:void(0)">show marker</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't hard, because when you add an info window to the map, the map scrolls to show the info window.

1. Make your map.
2. Make your sidebar.
3. Add markers to the map, while adding elements to the sidebar. Make the elements in the sidebar clickable, so that when you click on them you have something like this:

(This is from my own site.)

```
var marker =new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(searchResult.Latitude,searchResult.Longitude),
    map: googleMap,
    Title: searchResult.CompanyName
});
$('sideBarElement').addEvent('click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent("Some content for your info window.");
    infoWindow.open(googleMap,marker);
});
```

When you `.open()` and infoWindow, the map automatically pans to display it.

Answer (score 0):

( May be too late but if someone is googling for this )

Look into this question's answer which is exactly the samething I was looking for and now I found the answer [Open infobox on button clicked "OUTSIDE" map ( google map v3 )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226352/open-infobox-on-button-clicked-outside-map-google-map-v3/10240202#10240202)