# Open infobox on button clicked "OUTSIDE" map ( google map v3 )

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple marker.

I successfully able to openinfo box when clicked on each marker using this code ( yes its inside a loop of setting marker )

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
....
....
....
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            //alert(this.html);
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
}
```

The above code work very well.

But now i want each marker's infobox to open on button clicked outside the map. I tried something this in the same loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
....
....
....
 var chandu = document.getElementById(i);
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(chandu, "click", function(){
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
            //alert("Yo");
         });
}
```

and i have the html button to click like this

```
    <a href="#" id="0">0</a>
    <a href="#" id="1">1</a>
    <a href="#" id="2">2</a>
    <a href="#" id="3">3</a>
    <a href="#" id="4">4</a>
    <a href="#" id="5">5</a>
```

But this clicking of html link part doesn't woork

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The working solution I have now looks something like this

```
var chandu = document.getElementById(i);
chandu.onclick = generateTriggerCallback(marker,"click");
```

And there is a function out of the for loop

```
function generateTriggerCallback(object, eventType) {
            return function() {
                google.maps.event.trigger(object, eventType);
            };
        }
```

Credit: I come up with this answer after looking into the source code of this sample http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sidebar/random-markers.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're reusing 'this' in your code that handles the hyperlink clicks:

```
var chandu = document.getElementById(i);
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(chandu, "click", function(){
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
            //alert("Yo");
         });
}
```

The first 'this' is correct - this.html is the HTML of the hyperlink (NOT the marker).  The second 'this' in infowindow.open(map, this) is not correct.  In your working code, the this references the marker.  In your nonworking code, the this references the hyperlink.  The this object doesn't change between the two lines.  Instead of infowindow.open(map, this), you want infowindow.open(map, this.id) because the id value of your a tags is the same as the index in your marker array.

Note that this is incorrect HTML, though, because the id attribute can't start with a number, it must start with a letter.  If you were to attempt to validate your HTMl it wouldn't.  You need a letter prefix on the id values, perhaps an 'm'.  Then when you'd need to take the substring of the id value, stripping off the 'm' you have.

Comment: Yes, after a lot console.log, yesterday i realized the mistake I was doing with "this". And thanks for the info about the id attribute ( although now it works with the number starting first in id ). I am posting the solution as an answer.